# SQL - Converting a string to a date and / or time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting

I have a table with some rows. what i want is i want to show the sum of a particular field in the last row that will get generate automatically.

My SQL Code:

```
SELECT  
    Account,
    Amount = SUM(Amount),
    EndDate = CASE WHEN GROUPING(EndDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE EndDate END
FROM Test.dbo.T_OP
GROUP BY Account, EndDate WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(Account) =0;
```

The Error Message:
`Error converting a string to a date and / or time.`

If I change the else part I get the desired result only my date is not displayed.

The modified code:

```
SELECT  
    Account,
    Amount = SUM(Amount),
    EndDate = CASE WHEN GROUPING(EndDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE 'FakeDate' END
FROM Test.dbo.T_OP
GROUP BY Account, EndDate WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(Account) =0;
```

The Output:

```
Account Amount  EndDate
70000   776,98  FakeDate
70000   776,98  Total
70108   131,8   FakeDate
70108   60,3    FakeDate
70108   101,1   FakeDate
70108   40,8    FakeDate
70108   694,05  FakeDate
70108   1028,05 Total
```

How can I get that the date is played out correctly?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That query is product specific.

Comment: You have 2 columns `enddate` and `end_date` ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I Have one columns `end_date`. The second column was a error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `CASE WHEN` Part you are returning a `string 'Total'` but in `ELSE` Part you are returning a `date type value` so how can one column can have two types of data so you need to `cast your date to string type` as below :

```
CAST(End_Date AS VARCHAR)
```

OR

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, End_Date , 120)
```

Correted Query:

```
SELECT  
    Account,
    Amount = SUM(Amount),
    EndDate = CASE WHEN GROUPING(EndDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' 
              ELSE CAST(End_Date AS VARCHAR) END
FROM Test.dbo.T_OP
GROUP BY Account, EndDate WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(Account) =0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
EndDate = CASE WHEN GROUPING(EndDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE EndDate END
```

To:

```
EndDate = CASE WHEN GROUPING(EndDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE convert(varchar(25), EndDate, 120) END
```